# Jena/Fuseki : loading a custom implementation of com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.impl.GraphBase?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, fuseki

I wrote an implementation of [com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.impl.GraphBase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.4/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/impl/GraphBase.java)

```
package mygraph;
import (...)

public class MyGraph extends GraphBase
   {
   public MyGraph()
            {

            }
   @Override
   protected ExtendedIterator<Triple> graphBaseFind( TripleMatch m )
            {
            return //(...)
            }
   }
```

now, I'd like to load this graph into [Apache Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/index.html). I've read about the [Assembler](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/assembler.html) and the config (*.ttl) files but I'm lost. How should I tell Fuzeki to add/load my graph to its dataset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the steps outlined [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-dev/201210.mbox/%3C506D90DE.3020001@apache.org%3E).

Also, look at the source code for TDB to see how it registers (the com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.assembler package).

Comment: Thanks, it looks useful. How should I proceed with the 2nd step "Register an assembler (AssemblerUtils.registerWith)" with fuseki ?

Comment: You will need to use "[] ja:loadClass "yourclass" in a Fuseki config file to trigger some custom code.  See TDB.init and the fuseki example config file.